# Alsa external io plugin not working with pulse aludio

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, alsa, pulse-audio

I am developing ALSA plug-in based on ALSA PCM External Plugin SDK. Plug-in is source plug and has to convert PDM signal from microphone input to PCM used by Linux. I have succeeded to compile it using cmake and I have copied it to ALSA lib directory. I have updated *.asoundrc* file and make right PCM connection. I am able to record sound using this plug-in with *arecord* command. Unfortunatelly when I start *PulseAudio* server I got error message:

```
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)dlmisc.c: Cannot open shared library /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/alsa-lib/libasound_module_pcm_iopdm.so
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device temp: No such device or address
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-source" (argument: "device=temp"): initialization failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
```

I would like to use PulseAudio on top of my device because I am using Alexa which use PulseAudio. How to get things right? Where is the problem? If there is other solution available I would be grateful for it to.

PS. On the path given in this error message there is this plug-in.